# Users and Groups Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux

I'm having a problem. When I do `ls -la` I have this:

```
drwxr------ 2 mamie netusers 1024 Mar 31 10:50 mamie
drwxr------ 2 papy netusers 1024 Mar 31 10:45 papy
```

Basically, I want the user `mamie` (in group `netusers`) to be able to `rwx` in `/mamie` and only `r` in `/papy`. And vice versa for `papy`. If I put `rwxr-----` when I try to go in `/papy` using the user `mamie` it says I cannot access the directory. I have to add `x` but I only want `r`.

How can I do that please?

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? I'd like to be able to be mamie and go to /papy and read what's inside, without x

Answer (score 0):

in this case you need to give access with chmod

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /papy
```